# Allow only ROLE_ADMIN to manage users in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I have a Symfony 5.4 project using `sonata-project/admin-bundle` 4.9 and `sonata-project/user-bundle` 5.0.0-rc.1 and I want to let only the users with role `ROLE_ADMIN` to manage the users (CREATE/LIST/EDIT/DELETE), for other roles I want to hide the navbar menu entry and the dashboard entry for "Users".

In my `config/packages/sonata_admin.yml` I tried to specify a `sonata.user.block.menu` entry as found in some old questions but it seems that it does not exists anymore as the following error is thrown:

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The block type "sonata.user.block.menu" does not exist").`

As default I had only one admin_list block, I tried adding a sonata.block.service.rss and it is shown correctly in the dashboard but I can't find how to manage the Users block.

```
sonata_admin:
    title: 'Sonata Admin'
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            - { type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list, position: left }
            #- { type: sonata.user.block.menu, position: right, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN]}
            #- { type: sonata.block.service.rss, position: right, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN]}
    templates:
        layout: sonataLayout.html.twig


sonata_block:
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]
```

Any hints? Explicative picture following.

[image: Sonata Users disable based on roles]

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**. "Disabled both based on Role". It`s not "just add/change 2 lines"

> IMHO. "Basic" Sonata Admin`s configuration isn't too obvious. Therefore customize as much as possible -> to have more control.

I only could suggest U -> go this "right way" (surely,IMHO)

1. Create/manage the admin-menu with a event listener.
   U may read/check good example there [Using events to allow a menu to be extended](https://symfony.com/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/current/events.html) and the official -> [Sonata Admin -> KnpMenu](https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/5.x/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu/)

*With such approach -> U can easy manage menu items by your Roles. + other advantages surely*

2. From the very beginning -> create the custom templates. If U follow Flex & `/templates/admin` is the folder for Sonata Admin:

   ```
   // config/packages/sonata_admin:

      sonata_admin 
          ....

          templates:
              ....
              layout: '/admin/standard_layout.html.twig'
              knp_menu_template: '/admin/menu/knp_menu.html.twig' 
              dashboard: 'admin...
   ```

2* E.g. to extend the default layout. If your specific template do:

```
   {% extends '@SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig' %}
   
   {% block sonata_nav %}
       ...
```

> After these steps -> much more easy to control views by your Roles

Comment: thank you, I managed to remove the entry in the Menu, no success for the dashboard for now

Answer (score 0):

So, as per [documentation](https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/5.x/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu/#extending-the-menu) I added an event listener for the Menu and I was able to remove the entry from the left panel like this

```
//src/EventListener/MenuBuilderListener.php
<?php
namespace App\EventListener;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Event\ConfigureMenuEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

final class MenuBuilderListener
{
    private $security;
    public function __construct( Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function manageMenuItems(ConfigureMenuEvent $event): void
    {
        $menu = $event->getMenu();
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        if(!$user->hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")){
            $menu->removeChild('sonata_user');
        }
    }
}
```

With the service registered here

```
//config/services.yaml
app.menu_listener:
    class: App\EventListener\MenuBuilderListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sonata.admin.event.configure.menu.sidebar, method: manageMenuItems }
```

Then I added a firewall entry to manage permissions

```
//config/packages/security.yaml
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/app/sonatauseruser/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN]}
```

Till now I was not able to remove the Users entry from the dashboard, I tried to extend the dashboard twig template but it seems that the Users entry is added somehow later.

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/Core/dashboard.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% set has_left = false %}
    {% dump(blocks.left) %} //this shows only the admin group and not the user group
    {% for block in blocks.left %}
        {% if not has_left and (block.roles|length == 0 or is_granted_affirmative(block.roles)) %}
            {% set has_left = true %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
....
{{ sonata_block_render_event('sonata.admin.dashboard.top') }}
....
{{ sonata_block_render_event('sonata.admin.dashboard.bottom') }}
```

I also tried to bind both the render events .top and .bottom to a ConfigureEvent Listener but they are not fired (not sure if this is the right class of listener).

For now I found a sub optimal solution, I did an override of the userAdmin class like this

```
<?php
namespace App\Admin;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin as BaseType;

class UserAdmin extends BaseType
{
    protected function configureDashboardActions(array $actions): array
    {
        $actions = parent::configureDashboardActions($actions);
        unset($actions['list']);
        unset($actions['create']);
        return $actions;
    }
}
```

And registered it in

```
//config/packages/sonata_user.yaml
sonata_user:
    admin:
        user:
            class: App\Admin\UserAdmin
            controller: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
```

So the "Users" dashboard element is shown without any action available.